# use power BI to acquire a token from Azure AD, then pass it to API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I have a requirement to create Power BI dashboards consuming a REST API. However this API expects a Bearer token acquired from Azure AD. We're not embedding the Power BI into a web app. Is it possible to perform a request passing Application ID + Secret + Tenant, get the token, then pass it to the REST API in order to display the dashboards? In other words, chain http requests from Power BI (without using API Gateway / BFF approaches)

Comment: Yes, you can use client credential to get the token. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token

Comment: @TonyJu I know how to get the token, the problem here is how to chain http requests